# selenium cannot find iframe which appears in my browser

Tags: java, jquery, css, iframe, selenium

I try to run this code:

`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(frameBy));`

where `farmeBy.selector == #offer-carousel > div > div > div.item.popup.w-control-popup.active > div > div > div > iframe`

I get `no such element exception`.

How can it be if I get a result when I run in chrome inspection tool:

> $("#offer-carousel > div > div > div.item.popup.w-control-popup.active > div > div > div > iframe")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't specified the way to access the element.

From the code snippet you've given, you must be trying to use cssselector to locate the element. So, the code can be written like this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(frameBy)));
```

Or else, in case you have a name/id of the frame, you can use the below code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("name or id");
```

Or, you can use the index of the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

**Note:** The above code works only if there is just one iframe in the webpage. In case there are multiple, use the necessary index accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `findElement` didn't find your iFrame because you didn't specify if `frameBy` was an ID, a class or anything else. You should use `driver.findElement(By.id(frameBy))`.

Try the following:

```
String frameBy = "YOUR_FRAME_ID";
WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.id(frameBy));
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
```

---

Here is an alternative way that searches the first iframe no matter what your iframe ID is:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe").get(0));
```